# `"...".format(**ctx)` which skips unknown keys?

Tags: python

Is it possible to create a dict-like object that can be used in `str.format()` and that leaves unknown substitutions, i.e.:

```
ctx = Context(source='foo', name='bar')
print "{source}/static/{name}-{version}.min.css".format(**ctx)
```

should print

```
"foo/static/bar-{version}.min.css"
```

I tried with a simple `dict` subclass:

```
class Context(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, k):
        if k not in self: return '{%s}' % k
        return dict.__getitem__(self, k)
```

but that errors with `KeyError: 'version'`

Comment: the `{version}` is also treated as a placeholder for formatting. You might want to escape the `{}` by doubling: `{{version}}`

Comment: @schwobaseggl this question is about how to avoid such doubling, e.g. when you don't know which parameters are contained in the string and which are provided by the context.

Comment: Python 2 or 3? Python 3 has `format_map`, which makes this a lot easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python 3 introduced `str.format_map` for this:

```
class Context(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        return '{%s}' % key

ctx = Context(source='foo', name='bar')
print("{source}/static/{name}-{version}.min.css".format_map(ctx))
```

prints

```
foo/static/bar-{version}.min.css
```

One of the changes involved in adding `format_map` had the probably-unintended side effect that Python 3's `str.format` will also accept dict subclasses, but mappings that don't subclass `dict` need to be passed to `format_map`. I believe this new behavior of `str.format` is technically a bug. In any case, `format_map` is probably safer.

For Python 2, the [issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue6081) on the Python bug tracker leading to `str.format_map`'s inclusion suggests using `string.Formatter.vformat`:

```
import string
print string.Formatter().vformat("{source}/static/{name}-{version}.min.css", (), ctx)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Context(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, k):
        return self.get(k, '{%s}' % k)

>>> ctx = Context(source='foo', name='bar')
>>>
>>> print("{source}/static/{name}-{version}.min.css".format(**ctx))
foo/static/bar-{version}.min.css
```

Comment: [Doesn't work in Python 2.](http://ideone.com/ih7iJQ) I was pretty sure it wouldn't work in Python 3 either, but [apparently they changed the kwargs handling](http://ideone.com/JFYpZo).

Comment: BTW, I assume that this doesn't get into a `__getitem__` loop because `dict.get()` is implemented in C, not Python itself.  Given a Python definition of `dict.get()`, you might have to introduce `super` to make it work.

Comment: I think the fact that this works in Python 3 is a fluke, and possibly a bug. Dict subclasses seem to be passed through unchanged when used as kwargs to a built-in function or method, though they're converted to regular dicts when passed to functions written in Python. One of the changes to `str.format` to enable `str.format_map` in Python 3 made it so that `str.format` calls `PyObject_GetItem` instead of `PyDict_GetItem` for key lookup, with the side effect of making it so Python 3 calls your `__getitem__` instead of bypassing it. `format_map` is probably safer.